# Access constructor variables from another constructor in the same class

Tags: java, constructor

```
public GObject(Point3D[] v, Face[] f){
    vertex = v;
    face = f;
}

public GObject(String fileName){
    try{
           ...//read contents of file and store in an array
           Point3D[] vertices = new Point3D[numOfVertices];

    } catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Can't read file " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The second constructor reads the file that was passed to it and I've stored those values successfully in the vertices array but how can I pass the vertices array from the second constructor to the first one as a parameter so that `v = vertices`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` -

```
public GObject(String fileName){
    this(new Point3D[numOfVertices], new Face[5]); // `5` is just for example.

    try{
       ...//read contents of file and store in an array
       Point3D[] vertices = new Point3D[numOfVertices];

    } catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Can't read file " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Do note that if you use this approach, then call to `this` must be the very first statement of your second constructor. If this restriction is hard to follow for you, then I suggest you do something like this -

```
public GObject(Point3D[] v, Face[] f){
    setV(v);
    face = f;
}

public GObject(String fileName){
    try{
       ...//read contents of file and store in an array
       setV(new Point3D[numOfVertices]);
    } catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Can't read file " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void setV(Point3D[] v) {
    vertex = v;
}
```

I think the second approach is better, as it doesn't force you to construct a `Face` array just for the sake of calling the another constructor. Also you can later change the `setting logic` or incorporate validation easily.